# Probability of EventA is 60%. Probability of EventB is 80%. There's a 90% probability at least one will occur. What's the probability that both will?

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

The title says it all.
I don't know how to approach this problem, as I'm having trouble understanding exactly how to approach the inclusion/exclusion portion of this problem.

I figured out

> P(A∩B)=P(A)+P(B)−P(A∪B)

But I know I have to do something with the 90% bit.  Do I multiply above answer by 9/10?
Thanks!

Comment: Draw the Venn diagram. There are 4 cases: (1) that neither A nor B occurs, (2) that A occurs but not B, (3) that B occurs but not A, and (4) that both A and B occur. You are given the probabilities of Event A (namely cases 2 and 4), of Event B (namely cases 3 and 4), and of "at least one" (namely cases 2, 3, and 4). From this can you calculate the probability for just case 4?

Comment: I + Shreevatsar's comment: look at Venn's diagram. What's $P(A \cup B)$?

Comment: If A & B are independent, isn't the answer simply .6 * .8 * .9 ?

Comment: If A&B are independent, you could ignore the 0.9.

If P( ) is a function which assigns probability, P(A) = .6, P(B) = .8, P(A and B) = P(A)*P(B) = 0.8 * 0.9 = .72    Here, they both inhabit the 90% area in which at least one bill passes.  90% - (60%+80%) = -50%.  So, there is a 50% overlap, where both bills pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kinds of questions are easier when you draw the venn diagrams to represent each event.

Notice that since $0.6+0.8 > 1.0$ then clearly there's going to be overlap. You would draw this as two circles that have an overlapping section in the middle. This middle section will give you $P(A) \cap P(B)$.

Now normally you would find the probability of this middle section by taking $(60\%+80\%) - 100\% $. However in this case your total will not be $100\%$, it will be $90\%$.

Answer (score 1):

$P(A \cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cup B)$

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just calculate $P(A)P(B)$, that only works when the $A$ and $B$ are independent. Instead, think about how you would calculate the probability that at least one of $A,B$ will occur (which is 90%) if you were given $P(A)$, $P(B)$ and $P(A \cup B)$.